# Bootstrap mobile menu doesn't show in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a bootstrap theme for my wordpress website but the mobile menu doesn't show up when I make my browser window smaller
I've tried everything on stackoverflow so far, but whenever I try out another menu code, my menu gets tiny and pulled to the right side of my browser window. I don't know what the problem is.

Here's my menu code:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<?php if ( is_front_page() ) { ?>

<nav class="navbar navbar-home navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
  <!-- Mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/proformat_logotypewhite@2x.png" height="20" width="157"></a>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links for toggling -->
  <?php // Loading WordPress Custom Menu
     wp_nav_menu( array(
        'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse',
        'container_id'    => 'navbar-ex1-collapse',
        'menu_class'      => 'nav navbar-nav pull-right',
        'menu_id'         => 'main-menu',
        'walker'          => new Cwd_wp_bootstrapwp_Walker_Nav_Menu()
    ) );
  ?>
</nav>

  <div class="fullscreen-bg">
  <div class="hometext">
<h1 style="color: #ffffff;">VI ÄLSKAR BILDER.</h1>
<h4 style="color: #ffffff;">Vi gör tavlor på en mängd olika vis. Komponera din egen kombination av material och bearbetning eller välj bland våra färdiga lösningar.</h4>
</div>
<span class="read-more-container"><a class="scroll" href="#start">LÄS MER<br><img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/arrowdown.png" style="max-width: 50px;"/></a></span>
</div>

<?php } else { ?>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
  <!-- Mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/proformat_logotype@2x.png" height="20" width="157"></a>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links for toggling -->
  <?php // Loading WordPress Custom Menu
     wp_nav_menu( array(
        'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse',
        'menu_class'      => 'nav navbar-nav pull-right',
        'menu_id'         => 'main-menu',
        'walker'          => new Cwd_wp_bootstrapwp_Walker_Nav_Menu()
    ) );
  ?>
</nav>
```

I have two different menus on my website. One that is showing only on the front page, and another one on every other page. (they have different colors and logotypes)

EDIT:
The HTML code that is being rendered:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-home navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
  <!-- Mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://localhost:8888"><img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/proformat_logotypewhite@2x.png" height="20" width="157"></a>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links for toggling -->
  <div id="navbar-ex1-collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse"><ul id="main-menu" class="nav navbar-nav pull-right"><li id="menu-item-394" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-394"><a href="http://localhost:8888/material/">MATERIAL</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-393" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-393"><a href="http://localhost:8888/bearbetning/">BEARBETNING</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-392" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-392"><a href="http://localhost:8888/bildtjanster/">BILDTJÄNSTER</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-115" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-115"><a href="http://localhost:8888/kontakt/">KONTAKT</a></li>
</ul></div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML that is rendering for the nav? I'm guessing there is some class or structure error that you are missing which is preventing the mobile nav from properly showing up. I can't see it in the PHP, and I'm not entirely sure what exactly Cwd_wp_bootstrapwp_Walker_Nav_Menu() is doing, so the HTML would be helpful.

Comment: You have `pull-right` class on your `menu_class` that is being defined in `wp_nav_menu` array.  If you don't want the menu going to the right, remove `pull-right` from within there.  You can use CSS Media Queries to control the `pull-right` class on different screen sizes if you need it for big views, but don't on small views.

Comment: I have added the HTML that is being rendered to my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add navbar-default (or navbar-inverse) to

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-home navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
```

You can then use your custom navbar-home class to override the styles/colors. Or, if you are compiling the boostrap .less yourself, you can play with the colors for all the navigation/hover states in variables.less.

I would personally apply navbar-default to your homepage navigation and navbar-inverse to your internal page navigation and play with colors & styling from there, removing the need for the additional classes at all.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWZXvZ

Extras:

1. You are also missing a closing container div tag
2. You can use .navbar-right on the .navbar-collapse div.
3. You will need to make sure you are loading jquery and then bootstrap's JS for the toggle functionality.

Comment: Thank you! step 1 and 2 solved my problem. And I used navbar-default for the front page and navbar-inverse for every other page, then I just styled those like I wanted them to be. This made the toggle function work too! big thank you.